# Use current class as type constraint

Tags: ios, swift, types

I would like to have a convenience method on my class like so:

```
class BaseEvent {
  class func on(executionHandler: (BaseEvent -> Void)) -> Handler<BaseEvent> {
    return Handler<BaseEvent>(executionHandler: executionHandler)
  }
}
```

This has the downside that execution handler doesn't have the correct type for subclasses of `BaseEvent`. Imagine I had a class called `JumpEvent` that derived from `BaseEvent`, in an ideal world I would be able to do the following:

```
let handler = JumpEvent.on { event in
//Do something with jump event
}
```

Unfortunately the event is of type `BaseEvent` and would have to be downcast.

I've tried the following, with no luck:

```
class func on(executionHandler: (Self -> Void)) -> Handler<BaseEvent> {
return Handler<BaseEvent>(executionHandler: executionHandler)
}

class func on<T: Self>(executionHandler: (T -> Void)) -> Handler<BaseEvent> {
return Handler<BaseEvent>(executionHandler: executionHandler)
}
```

Note that the return type (`Handler<BaseEvent>`) isn't very important, just the type of the execution handler.

My current "solution" is the following, which requires manually redefining the method in subclasses which is obviously less than ideal:

```
class BaseEvent {
  class func on<T: BaseEvent>(executionHandler: (T -> Void)) -> Handler<T> {
    return Handler<T>(executionHandler: executionHandler)
  }
}

class JumpEvent: BaseEvent {
  override class func on<T: JumpEvent>(executionHandler: (T -> Void)) -> Handler<T> {
    return super.on(executionHandler)
  }
}
```

Please let me know if additional information is needed.

Thank you,
Noah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately rethought my implementation and achieved the desired results with generics. This might not work for all use cases, but it worked well for mine because the subclasses were the same as the base class except for their associated model object. So `BaseEvent` and `JumpEvent` changed to:

```
protocol ModelType {
}

class Jump: ModelType {
}

class Event<T: ModelType> {
   class func on(executionHandler: (Event<T> -> Void)) -> Handler<T> {
      return Handler<T>(executionHandler: executionHandler)
   }
}
```

This allows me to reuse functionality like I did with `BaseEvent`, with the added benefit that I don't need to create a new subclass for each model object.